# Reusing Async Pipe (Observable) Output

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I am trying to make use of the `async` pipe to display a table in Angular, but am getting the error: "...Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

My code:

```
<div *ngIf="studentList | async; else loading">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let student of studentList">
      <td>{{student.id}}</td>
      <td>{{student.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{student.last_name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  {{studentList | json}}
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
  <div>Loading ...</div>
</ng-template>
```

The back-end is returning an `Observable<Student[]>`

If I replace the `ngFor` with the below, it works but that means two `HTTP.get` calls are made, which I don't want:

```
<tr *ngFor="let student of (studentList | async)">
```

Is there a way for me to reuse the value of `studentList` from the `ngIf` within the `ngFor`, thus only making one request to my back-end?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A good practice is naming the observables with a $ sufix, lets say `studentList$` is of type `Observable<Student[]>`. You can use the `async` with `as` to get the studentList which is of type `Student[]` :

```
<div *ngIf="studentList$ | async as studentList; else loading">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let student of studentList">
      <td>{{student.id}}</td>
      <td>{{student.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{student.last_name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Apart from an amazing and simple answer by @ibenjelloun, I also wanted to add another approach by using `templateOutlet`

Pass on the evaluated `Observable` to an `ng-template` and use the template by `templateOutlet`. You can have something like this in your template:

```
<ng-container
    *ngTemplateOutlet="asyncTemplate;context:{listEvaluated: studentList | async}">
</ng-container>


<ng-template #asyncTemplate let-inputList="listEvaluated">
    <div *ngIf="inputList; else loading">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let student of inputList">
          <td>{{student.id}}</td>
          <td>{{student.first_name}}</td>
          <td>{{student.last_name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Please note: The `|` pipe operator in the `context` object works as a pipe and not as a bitwise operator.